# How to select a property from an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I have a `GroupBy` expression that has an anonymous type key with more than one property. I would like to store each property in a separate variable.

When I look at it in the debugger, `items.key` looks like this: `{ Location = Halifax, Address = abc, City = abcde }`.

How would I extract the individual properties of the anonymous type into a variable? Something like `var foo = items.key[Location]` ?

```
   private class ReportItem
    {
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string QA { get; set; }
    }
---
    finalReportList.Add(new ReportItem
    {
        Location = location,
        City = city,
        Address = address,
        UserName = name,
        QA = qa                        
    }); 

    var testquery = finalReportList.GroupBy(x => new {x.Location, x.City, x.Address});

    foreach (var items in testquery)
    {
        
        var location = items.Key; 
    }
```

Comment: `items.Key` is not a lambda expression, it is an anonymous type object. Why does your comment not match your `GroupBy`?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference anonymous type properties just as you would a "normal" object:

```
var testquery = finalReportList.GroupBy(x => new { x.Location, x.City, x.Address });

foreach (var item in testquery)
{
    var location = item.Key.Location;
    var city = item.Key.City;
    var address = item.Key.Address;
}
```